# difference between `for i in {1..$N}` and `for i in $(seq 1 1 $N) `

Tags: bash

I have the following in a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
...
for i in {1..$N}
   <loop content>
```

The above doesn't work and is only executed once where `i` has the value `{1..5}` 
(if `5` was provided as argument).

If I replace the above with:

```
for i in $(seq 1 1 $N)
```

.. then things work as expected. Why is that?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this Q: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-var-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence as well as this one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7998/which-bash-will-expand-1-var-in-the-same-way-that-zsh-does

Comment: @1_CR - you shouldn't have deleted that comment. When you did it that removed the duplicate Q that I was using to close this Q as a dup.

Comment: @slm, ooops, sorry. Faux pas on my part

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`{1..8}` is a form of brace expansion [introduced by `zsh` and supported by recent versions of `bash` and `ksh93`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92829/22565). In `bash`, it is done very early. In particular, it is done *before* variable expansion.

While `{1..8}` is valid, `{1..$N}` is not because `$N` is not a decimal number, it's the two characters `$` and `N` none of which are decimal digits.

Even if that worked, that would not be very efficient. The shell would have to allocate in memory a list made of the numbers 1 to `$N`. If `$N` was 10<sup>9</sup>, that would mean allocating gigabytes of memory.

`$(seq "$N")` is even less efficient. First, it's not portable. `seq` is a non-standard GNU command. Then doing `$(seq "$N")` means starting a new process, executing `seq` in it, the shell reading its output via a pipe and storing it in memory, then splitting that list (according to `$IFS`) and attempt to perform filename generation on it.

The space for the list resulting of that splitting and globbing has to be allocated as well.

A more efficient way to do it is to use the `ksh` `for (( ))` style of loop (also supported by `bash` and `zsh` for decades).

```
for ((i = 1; i <= N; i++)); do
   <loop content>
done
```

Or simply write it the portable and standard way, so you don't even have to use `bash`, and can use your (probably faster/leaner) system's `sh`:

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$N" ]; do
  <loop content>
  i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

Or maybe you can do it more the shell way by avoiding loops altogether. But we'd need to know what you want to do eventually to help there.

Answer (score 2):

[@1_CR is right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103121/difference-between-for-i-in-1-n-and-for-i-in-seq-1-1-n#comment157613_103121). This is a duplicate. The brace expansions happen first, before the variable, `$N`, has been expanded. Hence why the first example doesn't work. You're trying to brace expand 1 to a literal `$N`.

#### Example

What you're trying to do:

```
$ N=5
$ echo {1..$N}
{1..5}
```

When real values are used:

```
$ echo {1..5}
1 2 3 4 5
```

Also you're not really comparing apples to apples here. What gives you the impression that `{1..$N}` is equiv. to `$(seq 1 1 $N)`?

Other than producing a sequence of numbers, the braces (`{..}`) and the sub-shell ($(..)`) are 2 completely different notations.

Comment: You can use `eval echo ${1..$N}`. That will expand it like expected. But be careful with `eval`, as eval is evil and if it's possible to avoid its use, it's better to do it.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb I never use `eval`. It's a foolish command that shouldn't be included in the language (IMO)!

Comment: eval has valid uses. Rare,

Comment: @Patrick - sure, but there are more cases where you'll get burned, so better to avoid it. Generally if you need to use it, then your doing it wrong, IMO.