# Is it possible to use variables in count braces in Bash?

Tags: bash, arithmetic

I'm searching for a solution to a Bash 4 problem I have.

Bash 4 is able to iterate with leading zeros.

For the line:

```
for i in {001..005}; do echo -n $i" ";done;echo
```

the output is

```
001 002 003 004 005
```

but when I try this:

```
a="005"; for i in {001..${a}}; do echo $i;done
```

or something similar, the result is:

```
{001..005}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-var-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence is related, but not a duplicate: this question has the additional twist that leading zeroes are wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is the order in which brace expansion and variable expansion are applied. You must force the reverse order:

```
a=005
eval echo {001..$a}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions...](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

You could use `seq` instead:

```
$ a="005"; for i in $(seq -f %03g 001 ${a}); do echo $i;done
001
002
003
004
005
```

Answer (score 3):

Brace expansion happens very early during [expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) (first thing, in fact), before variable expansion. To perform brace expansion on the result of a variable expansion, you need to use `eval`, but that tends to be clumsy.

The easy way to iterate is to use a counter variable.

```
for ((i = 1; i < 5; i++)); do echo -n $i" "; done
```

To add the leading zeroes, you can format the number with printf:

```
for ((i = 1; i < 5; i++)); do printf "%03d " $i; done
```

An alternative trick is to count numbers that are a power of ten larger, and strip away the extraneous prefix.

```
delta=1000
for ((i = $((delta+1)); i < $((delta+5)); i++)); do echo -n "${i#1} "; done
```