# What is the purpose of eval?

Tags: shell, eval

1. What is the purpose of running a command with `eval`?
2. What kinds of commands can `eval` run? I find it can run builtin command, external executable command, pipeline, script. Can it run all kinds of commands which can be run in a shell directly?
3. Compare running a command directly in a shell and indirectly via `eval`. Is the difference only in that [with `eval` the command will be parsed twice instead of just once](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278370/674)?
4. Compare running a command via `eval` and via `command`. Assume that the command can be run by both. What differences are between the two ways?

Comment: link to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278427/why-and-when-should-eval-use-be-avoided-in-shell-scripts

Answer (score 2):

After the Command-line has been expanded:

> eval sends back the arguments to the first step of "Command-Line Processing".

All steps of [Command-Line Processing](http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html) are presented in this page.