# Combine brace and variable expansion in one line

Tags: bash, variable-substitution, tee, brace-expansion

I would like to have a logging function that takes filenames as arguments and replicate the stdout to all of these files. This is what I have come up so far:

```
function logger() {
    exec > >(tee -ia /var/log/{log1,log2})
}
```

When I try to replace `{log1,log2}` with `{$*}`, I get the arguments separated by space. So, I thought I would do something like this:

```
function logger() {
    exec > >(IFS=,; tee -ia /var/log{"$*"}
}
```

This fails to do what I want as brace expansion happens before moving on to the variable substitution. So, I thought I could do this:

```
function logger() {
    exec > >(IFS=,; eval "tee -ia /var/log/\{$*\}")
}
```

But this behaves the same, ie `logger one two` creates one single file named `{one,two}`.

Why is that? How can I get brace expansion to work so that `tee` writes to multiple files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use variable in a brace expansion in `bash`.  See e.g. [How can I use $variable in a shell brace expansion of a sequence?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-variable-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence)

If you don't want to call your `logger` function as

```
logger /var/log/log{1,2}
```

with the function written as

```
logger () {
    exec > >( tee -ia "$@" )
}
```

then what you could do is call it as

```
logger log{1,2}
```

or

```
logger log1 log2
```

and write the function as

```
logger () {
    for fname do
        set -- "$@" "/var/log/$fname"
        shift
    done
    exec > >( tee -ia "$@" )
}
```

or shorter (but more or less unreadable),

```
logger () {
    set -- "${@/#//var/log/}"
    exec > >( tee -ia "$@" )
}
```

or, if you wish,

```
logger () {
    exec > >( tee -ia "${@/#//var/log/}" )
}
```

This rewrites each element of the list of positional parameters by adding `/var/log/` to the beginning of each of them.  `tee` is then invoked with the list of modified arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, this is what I will probably end up doing. However, in the linked question, they explain that `eval rm foo.{$ext0..$extN}` can be used. In my case, why isn't brace expansion working even after adding the eval?

Comment: @user1371264 You're escaping the braces. Note also that I would not suggest using `eval` on external data. The log file names are external (to the function). If you have full control over these filenames, then it may be ok, but I would still rather use the method I showed here, as it additionally does not rely on the filenames being single words with no embedded  filename globbing characters etc.

Comment: Right! I thought I had to escape the braces in any case, but I was wrong. Could you update the answer to include this information as well?

Comment: @user1371264 I'll let someone else write a solution based on `eval` as it's not a a solution I would personally support using.  It's fragile and difficult to get completely right.

Comment: Didn't know the `set -- "$@" ...; shift` trick. Something new learned every day.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, yeah, that's a useful trick if you're restricted to a standard `sh`. Though in all ksh-like shells you could use a named array and `local array=(); for x do; array+=("$newitem")`. Which might be simpler to read, maybe.

Comment: @ilkkachu Oh, I wouldn't call it being "restricted"...  But I'd be the first to admit I'm partial to the POSIX syntax.