# Script which should remove supplied number of files deletes only a single file

Tags: bash, shell-script

My rather primitive shell script has two parameters:
first one is the location and the second is how many files need to be removed. For some reason it only removes one file even though I give the parameter for example 3.
Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..$2}
do
find $1 -type f | head -1 | xargs rm
done
```

**UPDATE**
This code seems to delete two files for some reason:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in eval {0..$2}
do
find "$1" -type f | head -1 | xargs rm
done
```

Comment: [How can I use $variable in a shell brace expansion of a sequence?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-variable-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence)

Comment: @steeldriver even with an eval it still deletes only one file :/

Comment: Now it deletes two files instead of 7 what is going on??

Comment: I really would suggest avoiding `eval` in this context - there are at least 2 cleaner, safer ways to do it (using `seq` or using a C-style `for` loop) in the linked Q&A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a precedence issue. Variables aren't interpreted inside bracket expansions because the bracket is evaluated *before* the variable is expanded. To illustrate, run this:

```
$ var=3
$ set -x
$ echo {0..$var}
+ echo '{0..3}'
{0..3}
```

As you can see, `echo {0..$var}` is expanded to `echo '{0..3}'`, so the literal string `{0..3}` and not `0 1 2 3` as you are expecting.

One way around this is to use `eval`:

```
$ eval echo {0..$var}
+ eval echo '{0..3}'
++ echo 0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3
```

So you could change your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(eval echo {0..$2})
do
    find "$1" -type f | head -1 | xargs rm
done
```

But that's both dangerous and ugly. This would be better:

```
#!/bin/bash
for((i=0;i<=$2;i++))
do
    find "$1" -type f | head -1 | xargs rm --
done
```

An even better version (if you are using GNU tools) with some basic safety tests and that can handle arbitrary file names (including files with newlines in their names) is:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
  echo "We need 2 arguments!"
  exit
fi
if [[ ! $2 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo "The second argument ('$2') must be a number!"
  exit;
fi

for((i=0;i<=$2;i++))
do
  find "$1" -type f -print0 | head -z -n 1 | xargs -0 -I {} rm -- {}
done
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the -- stand for in `xargs rm --`?

Comment: @SirMuffington [it signifies the end of options](https://askubuntu.com/a/794014/85695). That way, `rm *` can work with a file called `-f` for example. It's probably not needed with `xargs`, I think `xargs` handles this itself, but better safe than sorry.