# Bash Script fails to remove list of services from Firewalld

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, firewalld

I am attempting to clear out all existing services configured in `firewalld` via a bash script.

```
# produces {cockpit,dhcpv6-client,ssh} as an example
local EXISTING_SERVICES="{$(firewall-cmd --permanent --list-service | sed -e 's/ /,/g')}"
# firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service={cockpit,dhcpv6-client,ssh}
firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service="${EXISTING_SERVICES}"
```

When this is run, `firewall-cmd` returns:

```
Warning: NOT_ENABLED: {cockpit,dhcpv6-client,ssh}
success
```

The problem seems to be `firewall-cmd` interprets the list of services to disable as a single service name, instead of a list. When I run the command manually from the shell, the same exact (copy/pasted) command works like expected.

Example script to replicate:

```
EXISTING_SERVICES="{$(firewall-cmd --permanent --list-service | sed -e 's/ /,/g')}"
echo "firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service=${EXISTING_SERVICES}"
firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service="${EXISTING_SERVICES}"
```

Results:

[image: Shell results]

What is the difference between running this via script and via direct shell commands?

---

Update: Tried running the script with `set -x` as suggested by @fra-san, which produced the following results when run from the script:

[image: Results]

And the following results when run from the shell:

[image]

It seems the shell (and/or firewalld) behaves differently when run interactively and expands the list of services into 3 separate `--remove-service=` flags. This is very unexpected behavior.

Comment: The two `firewall-cmd` commands you are running are not equivalent to each other; using `set -x` to look at what is actually executed will likely be revealing. By the way, `firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service={cockpit,dhcpv6-client,ssh}` (the commented line) would work fine in your script, right?

Comment: @fra-san the existing services are unknown, so I cannot hard-code that line in as it's written in the comment... but yes, if hard-coded into the script it executes fine. I was suspecting an issue with bash variable expansion more than some issue with firewalld... I'll try set -x and see the results, didn't think of that actually!

Comment: @fra-san updated

Comment: Sorry, my fault: I should have specified that `set -x` is likely to be revealing if you use it when running the command interactively (the one that works). As you have found out, it doesn't tell much about what happens in your script.

Comment: @fra-san No, I should have known to try both... I'm not that green ;) - anyway, updated with a new screenshot... seems something (bash, or firewalld) interprets the command differently when run interactively... which is quite unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`firewall-cmd` has nothing to do with that, and the difference is not between running your command in a script and running it interactively. Rather, you are executing two fundamentally different commands.

What you are seeing in action is [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion): the command

```bsh
firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service={cockpit,dhcpv6-client,ssh}
```

is expanded by Bash into

```bsh
firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service=cockpit --remove-service=dhcpv6-client --remove-service=ssh
```

This happens both in scripts and on the command line. Note, however, that the result of expansions is never parsed by the shell in search of further expansion-triggering characters. Hence, the command

```bsh
firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service="${EXISTING_SERVICES}"
```

in your script is expanded to

```bsh
firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service={cockpit,dhcpv6-client,ssh}
```

and run in that form (the expression in curly braces is taken literally at that point).

That seems not to be a valid `firewall-cmd` command. Quoting [`man firewall-cmd`](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd), the syntax for `--remove-service` is

> ```
> ... --remove-service=service
> ```
>
> Remove a service. This option can be specified multiple times.

suggesting that the expected way of removing multiple services in a single run is

```bsh
firewall-cmd ... --remove-service=foo --remove-service=bar ...
```

Using Bash, you may use an array to store the enabled services and build the corresponding list of options to remove them:

```bsh
services=( $(firewall-cmd --permanent --list-services) )
firewall-cmd --permanent "${services[@]/#/--remove-service=}"
```

Where `${services[@]/#/--remove-service=}` is Bash's pattern-substitution form of parameter expansion — `#` matches the empty string at the beginning of each array element and replaces it with `--remove-service=`.

While less efficient, in some situations it may however be more practical to add/remove one service at a time, because the exit status of `firewall-cmd` is set to `0` if *at least* one operation succeeds, regardless of how many operations fail. You may then prefer something as:

```bsh
services=( $(firewall-cmd --permanent --list-services) )
for serv in "${services[@]}"
do
  firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service="$serv" || echo "failed: $serv" >&2
done
```

Comment: I should have known about brace expansion, having used it many times to create lists of directories... that's what I get for looking for the easy way to add/remove multiple services at once, tunnel vision and all. Nice catch!

Comment: No worries, overlooking things happens all the time, to anyone.

Comment: another possible solution to add to your answer is using `eval` to force the brace expansion to happen anyway. `eval firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service="${EXISTING_SERVICES}"`  - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-variable-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence

Comment: Yep. Though `eval` comes with caveats -- the risk of code injection and the need for sanitizing the value of the to-be-`eval`uated string (maybe not so relevant here, since the dynamic part would be the output of `firewall-cmd`). I added an alternative based on arrays which should be still readable and safer without adding much typing.

Comment: solid update! thanks again!