# Passing arguments into a glob pattern within a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, regular-expression, wildcards

I have a script called `get_numbers.sh`, which I want to use to extract data from `.pdf` files labelled sequentially by date, using `pdfgrep`.

Let me simplify my problem to what I believe are its essentials:

The `.pdf`s are named `file-07-01.pdf`, `file-07-02.pdf`, ..., `file-07-31.pdf`, where the numbers correspond to the month and day of the data in the file.

I can enter a shell command like
`pdfgrep -i "Total Number:"  file-07-{01..12}.pdf`

and I get exactly what I want, the appropriate text from each file for the dates 07-01 to 07-12.

I want to make a script for this, where all I have to do is enter the start and end dates as well as the month. This was my first go:

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash

    if [ "$#" -eq 3 ]
    then
        START_DAY=$1 
        END_DAY=$2
        MONTH=$3
    else
        echo "INCORRECT USAGE:"
        exit 1
    fi   


    pdfgrep -i "Total Number:" file-$MONTH-{$START_DAY..$END_DAY}.pdf
```

But doing `bash get_numbers.sh 01 12 07` gives me the error message

`pdfgrep: Could not open file-07-{01..12}.pdf`

Looking around, I've realized that you have to be careful when doing this, because the script will interpret `file-$MONTH-{$START_DAY..$END_DAY}.pdf` as a literal string rather than a glob. I've tried to modify this, by making this a variable, or putting double quotes around it, but it doesn't change the result. What am I missing?

Comment: It's the passing of arguments into the *brace expansion* that's the issue here - see for example [How can I use $variable in a shell brace expansion of a sequence?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-variable-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence). Personally I'd use `seq` rather than the accepted answer based on `eval`.

Comment: @steeldriver Ah, that did the trick - thank you. Switched to a for loop with `seq` like one of the later answers/examples, because `eval` was doing something funny with the search pattern. You learn something every day!

Comment: fwiw not sure if you realize that you can still pass all the filenames to a single pdfgrep if you assemble them into an array: `for m in $(seq -w "$1" "$2"); do files+=("file-$3-$m.pdf"); done` then `pdfgrep -i "Total Number:" "${files[@]}"`

Comment: I see, yes I was doing the `pdfgrep` inside the loop - this does seem to be noticeably faster. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Switch from `bash` to `zsh` which does have a decimal range glob operator (it can also, contrary to bash use variables in `{$start..$end}`, but that's not a glob operator).

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh -
if
  (( $# == 3 )) &&
    start_day=$1 end_day=$2 month=$3 &&
    [[ $start_day = <1-31> && $end_day = <1-31> && $month = <1-12> ]] &&
    (( end_day >= start_day ))
then
  pattern="file-<$month-$month>-<$start_day-$end_day>.pdf"
  exec pdfgrep -i "Total Number:" $~pattern(n) 
else
  print -u2 Incorrect usage
  exit 1
fi
```

`<1-5>` will match on any sequence of decimal digits that represent integer numbers from 1 to 5, including 2, 02, 002... That's why we also use `<$month-$month>` so that `<2-2>` can match on both `2` and `02`.

The `(n)` glob qualifier causes the glob expansion to sort numerically, so that `file-12-2.pdf` comes before `file-12-13.pdf` and `file-12-03.pdf` for instance.