# pass variable from shell script to GNU parallel

Tags: bash, environment-variables, gnu-parallel

I am using two shell scripts to set up a parallelization. The first script uses a for loop to pass an environment variable to the second script, which makes the call to parallel, which runs a julia script, again passing the variable.

The first (`test-loop.sh`) script looks like this:

```
for i in `seq 1 99`;
do 
export my_var=$i

bash  ~/PATH/TO/FILE/test-par.sh 
done
```

Then the next file (`test-par.sh`) looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

parallel julia ~/PATH/TO/FILE/bash-test.jl ::: {$my_var..100..1}
```

This above call to parallel to run Julia works fine if I replace the `$my_var` with 1 for example, but as soon as I add in the variable, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: invalid base 10 digit '{' in "{99..100..1}"
Stacktrace:
 [1] tryparse_internal(#unused#::Type{Int64}, s::String, startpos::Int64, endpos::Int64, base_::Int64, raise::Bool)
   @ Base ./parse.jl:137
 [2] parse(::Type{Int64}, s::String; base::Nothing)
   @ Base ./parse.jl:241
 [3] parse(::Type{Int64}, s::String)
   @ Base ./parse.jl:241
 [4] top-level scope
```

And I don't know how to reformat the call to parallel to fix this problem. Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: yes it does!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer was just to add `eval` like so:

```
eval "parallel julia ~/PATH/TO/FILE/bash-test.jl ::: {$my_var..100..1}"
```

Inspired by [How can I use $variable in a shell brace expansion of a sequence?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-variable-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence)