# How to loop over the number of lines of a file

Tags: bash

I wanted to loop over the lines of a text file `a.txt`. I know that if the file has e.g. 6 lines, I can do:

```
for c in {1..6} ; do echo $c; done
```

which prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

and I can count the number of lines as

```
wc -l a.txt | cut -f1 -d' '
```

which gives `2852`

Now when trying to substitute the `wc` count into the for loop as follows, the loop doesn't work:

```
for c in {1..$(wc -l ~/a.txt| cut -f1 -d' ')} ; do echo $c; done
```

Instead of printing the numbers from 1 to 2852, it prints:

```
{1..2852}
```

*How can I fix the sub-shell usage in the above loop to get the correct sequence of numbers?*

(
`bash --version` is (Debian):

```
GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

)

Comment: See [How can I use $variable in a shell brace expansion of a sequence?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-variable-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence) but more fundamentally [How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file)

Comment: If you use redirection `wc -l <~/a.txt` you get the count by itself and don't need `cut`. And if you only want to print the numbers you don't need a for loop, you can just run the `seq` program like `seq $(wc -l <~/a.txt)`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks a lot for the hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash don't have [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) feature to put a variable in brackets like

```
var=$(wc -l ~/a.txt| cut -f1 -d' ')}
echo {0..$var}
```

You can use a loop:

```
for ((i=0; i<var; i++)); do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Even if it's works, this should be avoided:

```
eval echo {0..$var}
```

`eval` is a common misspelling of 'evil'.
See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to know number of lines in a file to process it, just process it not even using a shell-loop; with `awk`:

```
awk '{ print "do something on line#", NR, $0 }' infile
```

in *awk*, the internal variable `NR` will return the **N**umber of **R**ecord(/Line) and `$0` is the content of that line which currently it is read for processing.